# Soundcloud OAuth request returns always invalid client

Tags: objective-c, oauth, soundcloud

Here is my objective-c code to obtain access token from SoundCloud:

`- (void) authoriseSoundcloud {
    NSString *apiUrl = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token";
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[ NSURL URLWithString:apiUrl]];
    NSString * params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@grant_type=password&username=%@&password=%@",client,secretKey,fldUsername.text,fldPassword.text ];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sharedSession];`

```
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                       }

                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];
```

}

However, I always get the result 401- `{"error":"invalid_client"}`.

However, that client ID works perfectly with those requests, that does not need authorization and I have checked multiple times, that my client ID and secret are correct. 
As there is not much samples for iOS to use those parameters in HTTP post body, I assume that maybe my parameters list is incorrect. Any ideas from Soundcloud engineers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a typo mistake, simply add "&" between "client_secret=%@" and "grant_type", like this :

```
NSString * params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=password&username=%@&password=%@",client,secretKey,fldUsername.text,fldPassword.text ];
```

Work like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I close the question?

Comment: Hi, just accept my answer as a correct answer for your question. thanks